# Combine 2 CSV files based on a match within a column disregarding the header row

Tags: php, python, csv, awk, merge

I have been scouring the ole interweb for this solution but have not found anything successful.  I have a CSV output from one script that has data presented in a specific way and i need to match that and merge with another file. Added bonus if i can round up to a simple 2 x decimal points.

File 1: dataset1.csv (using column 1 as a primary key or what i want to search the other file for.)

```
5033db62b38f86605f0baeccae5e6cbc,20.875,20.625,41.5
5033d9951846c1841437b437f5a97f0a,3.3529411764705882,12.4117647058823529,13.7647058823529412
50335ab3ab5411f88b77900736338bc6,6.625,1.0625,3
5033db62b38f86605f0baeccae5e6cbc,2.9375,1,1.4375
```

File 2: dataset2.csv (if column 2 matches column 1 of file join column 1 from file 2 replacing the data in column 1 of file 1.)

```
"dc2","5033db62b38f86605f0baeccae5e6cbc"
"dc1","5033d9951846c1841437b437f5a97f0a"
```

Desired results:

File 1 (or new file3):

```
dc1,3.35,12.41,13.76
dc2,20.875,20.625,41.5
```

Just to demonstrate that I have been trying to find a way, and not just randomly asking a question hoping someone else would solve my problem.

I have found a number of resources that say to use join.

`join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3 file 1 file 2` etc.  I have tested this a number of different ways.  I read on a number of posts that the results need to be sorted - with that long of a string its a little hard.  Not to mention file 1 may have 30 to 40 entries but file2 may only have 10.  I just need a name associated with the long string.

I started looking at grep - but then I will need a forEach loop to cycle through all the results and there has to be an easier way.

I have also looked at AWK - now this is a fun one trying to figure out exactly how to make this work.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]; next} $2 in a' file.csv testfile2.csv
```

Yeah.... tried many ways to get this to compare as this seems to be the general idea... but still haven't got it to work.  I would like this to be some type of shell script for linux to be very simple and something i can call from a php page and have it run.  Like if user hits refresh it churns through it and digests the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

j.

Comment: You don't mind which language the answer is based on? (PHP, python, awk)?

Comment: I am exploring all options - it just has to be simple and easily repeatable.... i am still testing some of the recommendations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of sort and gnu awk:

mergef.awk:

```
BEGIN   { FS= "[ ,\"]+"; }
FNR == NR { if ( !($1 in vals) ) vals [ $1 ] = sprintf("%.2f,%.2f,%.2f", $2, $3,$4) ;}
FNR != NR { print $2 "," vals[ $3 ]; }
```

Say your files are f1.csv and f2.csv then use this command:

```
awk -f mergef.awk f1.csv f2.csv | sort
```

- the first line in the script deals with the quotes present in the second file (because of this setting there is an empty field `$1` for the second file)
- the second line reads in the first file. The `if` takes care that only the first occurence of a key is used.
- the last line prints the *new* keys from the second file along the stored values from the first file, retrieved via the *old keys*
- `FNR == NR` is true for the first file

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you! Additional question how would i drop the ones that don't have a matching record? This is with the help of your script - 12k,
small-4K,
small-Gen5,804.12,173.88,977.35
small-2K,
small-1,   i want to drop the ones that don't have any addtional records.

Comment: @Jared Where are these records? Are they in the second file? Because rowd in the first file without a pairing in the second file are already dropped.

Comment: @Jared To drop lines from the second file without pairing in the first, change the last line of the script to `FNR != NR { if( $3 in vals) print $2 "," vals[ $3 ]; }`

Comment: basically in file 2 there is dc1 and number string ... in file 1 if there isn't a match that matches in file2 then drop the ones that don't match.  Essentially if data in file 1 doesn't exist in file 2 then i don't need it in the output.

Comment: also modifying the last line added some errors with the output... it grabbed the header in the output and matched it to something.   awk -f mergef.awk file1.csv file2.csv | sort
7NA_01,0.00,0.00,0.00
Name,0.00,0.00,0.00  -->> this is the header in file2
dc1,0.69,1.00,1.00
dc2,1.92,1.04,1.31

Comment: actually on the original example you gave -the header got matched as well Name,0.00,0.00,0.00... don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Using `python` and the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the csv files.
df1 = pd.read_csv(dataset1.csv, header=None, index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(dataset2.csv, header=None, index_col=1)

# Round values in the first file to two decimal places.
df1 = df1.round(2)

# Merge the two files.
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

# Write the output.
df3.to_csv(output.csv, index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

except formatting the numbers this does the job

```
$ join -t, -1 1 -2 2 -o2.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 <(sort file1) <(tr -d '"' <file2 | sort -t, -k2)

dc1,3.3529411764705882,12.4117647058823529,13.7647058823529412
dc2,2.9375,1,1.4375
dc2,20.875,20.625,41.5
```

note that there two matches for dc2.

Bonus: for required formatting pipe the output of the previous script to

```
$ ... | tr ',' ' ' | xargs printf "%s,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f\n"

dc1,3.35,12.41,13.76
dc2,2.94,1.00,1.44
dc2,20.88,20.62,41.50
```

but then, perhaps `awk` is a better alternative.  This is to show that no programming is required if you can utilize existing unix toolset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with PHP:

```
foreach (file("dataset1.csv") as $line_no => $csv) {
    if (!$line_no) continue; // in case you have a header on first line
    $fields = str_getcsv($csv);
    $key = array_shift($fields);
    $data1[$key] = array_map(function ($v) { return number_format($v, 2); }, $fields);
};

foreach (file("dataset2.csv") as $csv) {
    $fields = str_getcsv($csv);
    if (!isset($data1[$fields[1]])) continue;
    $data2[$fields[0]] = array_merge(array($fields[0]), $data1[$fields[1]]);
};

ksort($data2);

$csv = implode("\n", array_map(function ($v) {
    return implode(',', $v);
}, $data2));

file_put_contents("dataset3.csv", $csv);
```

NB: As you mentioned that the first file will be *using column 1 as a primary key*, a duplicate key value should not occur. If it does, the last occurrence will prevail.

Comment: with this - is there a way to drop the records that didn't have a matching string?

Comment: Yes, I just added a line of code (using `isset`) to skip entries from the second file that do not match with keys from the first.

Comment: 7NA_01,0.00,0.00,0.00
Name,,,

Correction not an error it does output to the file but much like the top awk example its matching name to something.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you just wrote... can you clarify what the issue is you raise?

Comment: my bad i edited it and it removed everything else i had.  I thought i had an error but i was able to get it working.  The output of your script even the script above it matches one of the records to the headers. thats what your seeing there name shows up there.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get from the question you had headers. I updated my answer so the first loop ignores the first line, i.e. the header.